# Does this function grows faster than any exponential function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I need following result in understanding of a result given in a paper.Any ideas to prove this?

Consider the function $\hat {M}: \bf R \to R$ defined as $$\hat{M}(y)=\int_{\bf R}\vert f(x) \vert e^{\vert xy\vert}dx$$.

> Let $f \in L^1(\bf R)$, $f$, and $\hat {f}$ does not have compact support then show that $\hat {M}$ grows faster than any exponential function.

Comment: let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ elsewhere then the support is not compact and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $M(y)=0$. Maybe you forgot a condition

Comment: I think by "support" he means the essential support, since we are working in $L^1$.

Comment: @Hugo yes,thats correct!

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? I do not use $\hat f$ has non-compact support...

Comment: Dear @Hugo I think your solution is okay.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma. Either for every $M$ one has
$$
\int_M^\infty \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx > 0
$$
or for every $M$ one has
$$
\int_{-\infty}^M \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx > 0.
$$

Proof. If by contradiction there exist $M_1, M_2$ such that
$$
\int_{M_1}^\infty \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx = 0
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{M_2} \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx = 0,
$$
then $f$ is zero almost everywhere outside the interval $[M_2,M_1]$, which contradicts the non-compact support hypothesis.

Assume now, wlog, that the first holds. Fix $p>0$, and set $c = \int_{2p}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx > 0$; observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\hat{M}(y)}{e^{p\lvert y \rvert}} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f(x) \rvert e^{(\lvert x \rvert - p)\lvert y \rvert}\, dx \geq \int_{2p}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert e^{(x - p)\lvert y \rvert}\, dx \geq e^{p\lvert y \rvert} \int_{2p}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx = ce^{p\lvert y \rvert}
\end{align*}
which tends to $\infty$ as $y \to \pm \infty$. Since $p$ was arbitrary we are done.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped this comment!